# Change pref. value in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3

I changed my Xcode version to 8 and Swift version to 3.

I would like to know the syntax of

```
func isActPack(){

  if((self.prefs.value(forKey: "activePack") as AnyObject).count > 0){
        print("Hello")
    }
   else {
   print(“Hi Everyone”)
}
```

in Swift 3?

Because my app got error and could not continue from this step.

I don't know how to change that in Swift 3.

Comment: What is the data type for "prefs"?

Comment: @Ragul Probably `UserDefaults.standard` ...

Comment: Can you show the declaration part?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming just for the example that the value that contains the key **activePack** is an array of integers:

```
let prefs = UserDefaults.standard
prefs.setValue([1, 2, 3], forKey: "activePack")
```

so certainly you know what kind of type holds **activePack** key

---

```
let activePack = prefs.value(forKey: "activePack") as? [Int]

// we're making sure that activePack is not nil
// and after that also checking that
// it containts at least one item    
if let items = activePack, items.count > 0 {
  print(items)
}
```